# .htaccess Rewrite Rule doesn't work on my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

how i can rewrite this url:

```
http://www.example.com/album?album_id=52
```

to this:

```
http://www.example.com/album/52
```

my .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^album/$ album?album_id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture album id from your pattern first before you can use it as `$1`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)/?$ album?album_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: can i do anything else for you? :D